# How do I convert sql to excel syntax?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, mysql, database

I have two sheets in an excel file, "sheet1" and "sheet2".

The first sheet has a table called Oranges, it shows where the oranges were produced and where they were exported to:

[image: sheet1]

On the second sheet I need to track the amount of oranges coming from and going to certain locations. Here is my desired result:

[image: sheet2]

I currently have this formula for cell C3:

```
=SUMIFS(Oranges[[#Headers],[Quantity]],Oranges[[#Headers],[Produced In]],"=California",Oranges[[#Headers],[Exported To]],"=British Columbia")
```

Unfortunately this just returns 0

I don't know excel very well which is why I need help with this, but the SQL equivalent would be

select sum(quantity) where producedIN = "California" AND exportedTo = "British Columbia"

Just having a hard time translating this into excel syntax.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the `[#Headers]` argument or the `=` in the condition -

```
=SUMIFS(Oranges[Quantity],Oranges[Produced In],"California",Oranges[Exported To],"British Columbia")
```

I know it gets sort of confusing when working with [Tables].

Comment: thanks for the help this put me on the right track to find the solution 

=SUMIFS(Oranges[[#Data],[Quantity]],Oranges[[#Data],[Produced In]],"=California",Oranges[[#Data],[Exported To]],"=British Columbia")

Comment: Are there any tool that can convert your complex SQL statement to excel formula ? I need that because business people don't understand SQL only Excel .

Comment: @osamaalbanna are you asking jysk16?

Comment: @Raystafarian NOPE I'm asking anyone who can help .